# Need help with showing a basis trig identity: $|\cot(\pi z) |^{2}=\frac{\cos^{2}(\pi x)+\sinh^{2}(\pi y)}{\sin^{2}(\pi x) + \sinh^{2}(\pi y)}$.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Let $z=x+iy$. I want to prove:

$$|\cot(\pi z) |^{2}=\frac{\cos^{2}(\pi x)+\sinh^{2}(\pi y)}{\sin^{2}(\pi x) + \sinh^{2}(\pi y)}.$$

I've been able to show that
\begin{align*}
    |\cot(\pi z) |^{2} &= \biggl| \frac{\cos(\pi z)}{\sin(\pi z)} \biggr|^{2}   \\
    &=\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{\sin(\pi z)} \cdot \frac{\overline{\cos(\pi z)}}{\overline{ \sin(\pi z)}}\\
    &=\frac{\cos(\pi z) \cos(\pi \overline{z})}{\sin(\pi z) \sin(\pi \overline{z})}.
   \end{align*}

From here I tried using the formulas $\cos(\pi z) =\frac{e^{i\pi z}+e^{-i\pi z}}{2}$ and $\sin(\pi z) = \frac{e^{i\pi z}-e^{-i\pi z}}{2i}$ but things got very involved and I could not get what I want. I also tried going from the RHS of the formula I want to the LHS but that didn't work either. I'd appreciate if someone can please just show me how to do the computations.

Comment: Use the addition formula for cotangent.

Comment: @K.defaoite That's a good hint. Thanks I'll try that.

Comment: @K.defaoite Actually, I'm still not seeing it. The computations I'm doing don't appear to be taking me where I want to go, and I'm not sure how the hyperbolic functions would get involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sin(z_1 + z_2) = \sin(z_1) \cos(z_2) + \cos(z_1) \sin(z_2)$. Taking $z_1 = x$ and $z_2 = iy$, we get $\sin(x + iy) = \sin(x)\cos(iy) + \cos(x)\sin(iy)$. Therefore
$$\sin(x+iy) = \sin(x) \cosh(y) + i\cos(x)\sinh(y)$$
A similar calculation with $\cos(x + iy)$ gives us
$$\cos(x+iy) = \cos(x) \cosh(y) - i\sin(x)\sinh(y)$$
Therefore
$$|\cos(z)| = \cos(z)\cos(\overline{z})\\
= [\cos(x) \cosh(y) - i\sin(x)\sinh(y)]\cdot[\cos(x) \cosh(y) +i \sin(x)\sinh(y)]\\
=\cos^2(x)\cosh^2(y) +\sin^2(x)\sinh^2(y)\\
=\cos^2(x)(1+\sinh^2(y)) +\sin^2(x)\sinh^2(y)\\
=\cos^2(x) + \sinh^2(y)$$
Moreover
$$|\sin(z)| = \sin(z)\sin(\overline{z})\\
= [\sin(x) \cosh(y) + i\cos(x)\sinh(y)]\cdot[\sin(x) \cosh(y) - i\cos(x)\sinh(y)]\\
=\sin^2(x)\cosh^2(y) +\cos^2(x)\sinh^2(y)\\
=\sin^2(x)(1+\sinh^2(y)) +\cos^2(x)\sinh^2(y)\\
=\sin^2(x) + \sinh^2(y)$$
So finally we have:
$$\left|\cot(z)\right| = \frac{\cos^2(x) + \sinh^2(y)}{\sin^2(x) + \sinh^2(y)}$$
Your result follows